# How to change id of a button element at runtime using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, html-table

In my HTML page there is a table where users can add rows at runtime. In one of the columns of the table there is a button which is being inserted at page on load like the following:

```
function funcAddBtnOpenPad() {   // This funct being called at page onload
// VARS FOR ADDING BUTTON IN CELL "5"
// STORING BUTTON ATTRIBUTES
var btnOpenPad = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', id:'idBtnOpenPad', class:'clsBtnOpenPad', name:'btnOpenPad', value:'OpenPad' });

$('#childTable tr').each(function(tempRowIdx) {
    
// CONSTRUCT TAG FOR BUTTON "OpenPad" IN CELL "5"
    tempButtonCellTag = 'id_tIndx'+tempRowIdx+5;

// HERE WE ARE INSERTING THE BUTTON "OpenPad" <<<<
        $('#'+ tempButtonCellTag).append(btnOpenPad);
        $(this).attr('id', 'btnOpnPad'+tempRowIdx);    // <<< Tried this to change the `id` but not working
});

}
```

However, on adding new rows the `id` of the buttons in the newly added rows remain the same (rightly so). I have tried to change the `id` of the dynamically added buttons, as I have shown above (<<<), but it fails to change the `id` of the button.

**Questions is: How can I change the `id` of the buttons to have different values?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing attribute of `tr`, not button,

Try with replacing your last line solution :

```
$(this).find("input[type='button']").attr("id", "btnOpnPad" + tempRowIdx);
```

So, your final function code should be

```
function funcAddBtnOpenPad() {   // This funct being called at page onload
var btnOpenPad = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'button', id:'idBtnOpenPad', class:'clsBtnOpenPad', name:'btnOpenPad', value:'OpenPad' });

   $('#childTable tr').each(function(tempRowIdx) {
    
    tempButtonCellTag = 'id_tIndx'+tempRowIdx+5;

        $('#'+ tempButtonCellTag).append(btnOpenPad);
        $(this).find("input[type='button']").attr("id", "btnOpnPad" + tempRowIdx);
   });

}
```